# How to check the previous record in CursorAdapter - Android

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I have a chat application and I'm looking for a way to hide the profile image of the chat when the there are two or more consecutive chat for the same person, how can I do that?  or may be use different chat bubble like facebook or other chat apps

Below is a sample of what I have,

```
   private static class ChatCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private ChatCursor chatCursor;

        public ChatCursorAdapter(Context context, CommentsCursor cursor) {
            super(context, cursor, 0);
        chatCursor = cursor;
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_layout, parent, false);
        }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Chat chat = chatCursor.getChat();   
        //If the previous chat was from the same 
        //person set the profile image to invisible
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly this can help you.

```
@Override
public View newView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    int posBeforeLast = cursor.getCount() - 1;
       //Also can use to check current position of the cursor
    int currentPostion= cursor.getPosition();
}
```